# Find and Partially Replace Notepad++ Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with a file with lines containing a space, 9 digits, 6 spaces and 5C18. Finding it is easy I'm using

```
\s\d{9}\s{6}\5C18
```

The problem is that I need to replace the space at the beginning of the line with a letter, say F. So that everything else remains in tact. Every time I try to do it the entire line is replaced with the expression. I know this is probably something stupidly basic but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not think you meant to escape `5`, so you must have `\s\d{9}\s{6}5C18`. Which space must be turned to `F`? Also, if it is a text on a single line, use `\h` instead of `\s`

Comment: Look into capture groups, using parenthesis. I'm not sure if notepad++ supports those, but that would be the way to do it.

Comment: It's text on a single line. The F needs to go where that first space is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Do you mean there are lines in format of `\s\d{9}\s{6}5C18` or lines that contain it? are you trying to replace the `\s` in `\s\d{9}\s{6}5C18` with an `F` or you mean the  space  at  the beginning of  line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the part that you do not wish to replace into a *lookahead expression*:

```
^\s(?=\d{9}\s{6}5C18)
```

Now the portion in `(?= ... )` is not considered part of the match; only the initial space is. Hence, running a replace with this regex would let you replace the initial space with whatever characters that you want.

> It's text on a single line. The F needs to go where that first space is at the beginning of the line.

Note the use of `^` anchor to ensure that the match of the initial space is tied to the beginning of the line.

Comment: I appreciate it, I misread your comment at first thinking that I needed to put it into the replace line(I know I know I'm hopeless). Once I wisened up that worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help!